# ItemsControl and DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf

Seems that it takes some time for a datatemplate to be set into a newly created item. This is simiar to [How can I retrieve the DataTemplate (and specific objects) of an item in an ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269319/how-can-i-retrieve-the-datatemplate-and-specific-objects-of-an-item-in-an-item) but that doesnt provide a satisfactory answer as well.

```
var newIndex = this.Items.Add(new object()); // new "data"
var newContainer = (ContentPresenter) this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(newIndex);
var uiElem = newContainer.FindName("txt");
```

The call to findname will return null, and so VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount = 0. If I give it some time, the template is bound and all is well, but that's non-deterministic. Does anyone know of an event or a way to force the template to be bound immediately?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to run your code at a later [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) than Render so your code runs after the Rendering has occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications can call [ApplyTemplate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx) to guarantee that the visual tree of an element is complete. This guarantee step might be necessary if code will be checking the child elements in the tree.